# No module named 'manipulation'

Tags: drake

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS via WSL and working on Python 3.10. When I try to run Drake tutorials locally with `python3 -m pydrake.tutorials` I get the following error: `ERROR: the Jupyter notebook runtime is not installed!` which is not the case since I already installed jupyter-notebook using `sudo apt-get install jupyter-notebook` and can easily open a jupyter notebook myself when typing `jupyter notebook`.

Additionally, I tried to copy-paste and run the following code from a tutorial:

```
import pydot
from IPython.display import HTML, SVG, display
from pydrake.all import (AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, DiagramBuilder,
                         FindResourceOrThrow, GenerateHtml,
                         InverseDynamicsController, MeshcatVisualizer,
                         MeshcatVisualizerParams, MultibodyPlant, Parser,
                         Simulator, StartMeshcat)
from manipulation import running_as_notebook
```

and i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manipulation'
```

It seems as I don't have a module called manipulation except the one inside pydrake library. Is this a version issue?
I desired to mention it in case the two errors are interconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the tutorials in Drake import anything from `manipulation`.  The manipulation textbook repository examples absolutely do.  You can find more about those here: https://manipulation.csail.mit.edu/drake.html .

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out but that doesn't solve the issue I mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: Check the console output; I suspect there are errors there that will help you resolve what's not working with your jupyter installation.